# How to get all dates informatiın from csv file with for loop?

Tags: python, filtering, export-to-csv, date-range, pandas-loc

I want to get each day information with the for loop. Because I will show responding weekly data as a table in another code. But when I did this I got Empty Dataframe.

```
 df = pd.read_csv('yogun_bakim_yatak.csv', encoding="utf-8")  
    df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
    time = pd.date_range(start="2020-12-25 00:00:00+00:00", end="2021-12-25 00:00:00+00:00", freq="D")
    # Filter data between two dates
    n = len(time)
    for i in range(0, n, 1):
     filtered_df = df.loc[(df['created_at'] == time[i]]
      print(filtered_df.to_string())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the below code snippet instead of 'for' loop, I believe it is much more efficient

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2020-12-25 00:00:00+00:00')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2021-12-25 00:00:00+00:00')

df[df['date'].dt.date.between(start_date, end_date, inclusive=True)]
```

setting `inclusive` as `False` is equivalent of `>` and `<`
While, `True` is equivalent of `>=` and `<=`